# Laravel passport multi-tenant clients

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have an application which is a REST gateway for remote PostgreSQL database and I use Passport for authentication.

This app is composed by a local MySQL database for oauth, users, roles, permissions, ... and a remote PostgreSQL with data to serve.

I need to affect a tenant for each clients (personal and password clients) like this:

```
Client A: can fetch data from schema X
Client B: can fetch data from schema Y
Client C: can fetch data from schema X and Y
```

What is the best way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a common problem, unfortunately SO is not the correct network you ask these kind of questions, because answer will be long or many answers may be correct (opinionated). This is simply problem that can not be reproduced on "coding" level, I am afraid that this is going to get closed.

Comment: Hi @Kyslik, thank you for your reply, my question is relative to Laravel Passport package and you are right answers may opinionated and it's what I want, I have an idea for the way I can do this but I want also opinions of other users. :)